# Where to place a script, which clones gdm greeter to screen and beamer?

Tags: gdm

In Ubuntu 16.04 I could clone the ligthdm-greeter screen for PC and beamer on about 40 machines with following script placed in /usr/local/bin:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Sleep until System has configured Resolutions
sleep 8
# Find 1. Screen
SCREEN1=$(xrandr --query | awk '/ connected /{ print $1 }' | head -1)
# Find 2. Screen
SCREEN2=$(xrandr --query | awk '/ connected /{ print $1 }' | tail -1)
# Set Resolution
RESOLUTION=$(xrandr --query | awk '/^ *[0-9]*x[0-9]*/{ print $1 }' | sort -g -r | uniq -d | head -1)
# Set Clone Modus with Maximum Resolution 
xrandr --output $SCREEN1 --mode $RESOLUTION $RATE_OPTION --output $SCREEN2 --mode $RESOLUTION  --same-as $SCREEN1
```

called from `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-scripts.conf` with option `greeter-setup-script="/usr/local/bin/clone"`.

Where can I link/install/call the same script in gdm/gdm3 on Ubuntu 17.10 /18.04 to get cloned greeter screens?

Comment: Are you using the lightdm greeter in 17.10? If not ... nowhere and you will need another script calling the greeter

Comment: No, I am not using the lightdm greeter. I would like to maintain the Ubuntu standard.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a .desktop file e.g. `clone.desktop` in directory `/usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart` containing a link to `/usr/local/bin/clone` will dynamically clone the gdm-greeter to PC-screen and beamer-screen, so both screens will show login information and make login possible.

Contend of `clone.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Clone PC Screen and Beamer Screen for Login
Exec=/usr/local/bin/clone
Terminal=false
NoDisplay=true
```